# If string matches regex replace, if not add variable

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using javascript to append a string to a variable (adding specific image size to a slider on mobile devices).

Here's the line I'm using.

```
var newsrc = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf(".")) + "-420x320" + src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("."));
```

However there are some cases where the image src has another size and in this case I would like to remove that size and add the one above.

Example:
Both

```
 http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg-700x703.jpg and
 http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg.jpg
```

Needs to be:

```
 http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg-420x320.jpg
```

What would you use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to build a pattern with an optional part:

```
src = src.replace(/(?:-\d+x\d+)?\.jpg$/, '-420x320.jpg');
```

where `(?:-\d+x\d+)?` is an optional non-capturing group and `$` is an anchor for the end of the string.

Comment: I like this as it also adds in the desired dimensions as part of the replace.

Comment: Your works exactly as I want except for the fact that is limited to .jpg extensions. How could I go to make it extension independent?

Comment: You could try `/(?:-\d+x\d+)?\.[a-zA-Z]+$/` if you're not picky about the filetype. This will match a `.` followed by any combination of lowercase/uppercase letters, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Replace `jpg'` with (?jpg|png|gif|whatever). You might also consider adding the `i'` option ignore character case) after the RegExp to allow for upper/lower case chars.

Comment: Excellent, A combination of both Paul's and HBP solutions fit my needs. I'm marking this an solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick in a quick replace that matches the `-#x#` pattern and replaces it with a blank.

`var newsrc = src.replace(/(-\d+x\d+)/,"").substring(0, src.lastIndexOf(".")) + "-420x320" + src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("."));`

Comment: Yours add the 420x320 size at the end of the string, without replacing the other

Answer (score 0):

FIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/9u8m9oob/1/

You can achieve the same using below way also:

```
var str1='http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg.jpg';
var str2='http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg-700x703.jpg';
var regex=/^(http:\/\/domain\.com\/)(\d+jpg)(.)*(\.jpg)$/g;
var result= str1.replace(regex,"$1$2-420x320$4");
console.log(result);  // gives output as http://domain.com/10001428289243jpg-420x320.jpg
```